# Скрыть блок при клике за его пределами?

Tags: javascript

```js
$('.select_box').click(function () {
  $(this).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.select_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.option_box li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.option_box li:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
.option_box.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">1</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
      <li class="options">3</li>
      <li class="options">4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">2</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как можно скрыть блок, если кликнуть за его пределами. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой ответ, это доработанный ответ, который дал @Избыток сусликов

Дело в том, что постоянно следить за кликами по документу, это очень ресурсозатратно, особенно если учесть, что каждый раз при клике проверяется наличие класса *select_box* у элемента по которому кликнули и у всех его родителях. Поэтому я вынес поиск в отдельную функцию, которая начинает работать, только после того как меню активируется и перестает работать, когда сработает условие для закрытия меню. Тем самым решается проблема описанная выше.

```js
$('.select_box').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
    // Начинаем следить за кликами по документу
    $(document).bind('click', HandlerPar);
});

function HandlerPar(e) {
    // Если кликнули за пределами select_box
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("select_box") &&
        $(e.target).parents(".select_box").length === 0) 
    {
    // Удаляем класс open у классов option_box
        $(".option_box").removeClass("open");
    // И перестаем следить за кликами по документу
        $(document).unbind('click', HandlerPar);
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.select_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.option_box li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.option_box li:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
.option_box.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="container">
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">1</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
      <li class="options">3</li>
      <li class="options">4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">2</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это хорошее решение.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.select_box').click(function () {
  $(this).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("select_box") 
        && $(e.target).parents(".select_box").length === 0) 
    {
        $(".option_box").removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.select_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.option_box li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.option_box li:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
.option_box.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="container">
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">1</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
      <li class="options">3</li>
      <li class="options">4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
      <span class="number_val">2</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="options">1</li>
      <li class="options">2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery + чистый js. Добавьте к js такой код.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains("select_box") == false) {
    $(".option_box").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```